# is it possible to change the way of authenticating linux with the help of a daemon (FC4 particularly)?

Tags: fedora, authentication, daemon

I got a pc and a special application installed on it, the OS is FC4 and we don't have root password I tried several random passwords and after 3 times I realized that something fishy is happening behind the scene then I boot up with rescue disk and checked the hard disk and realized some files missed(deleted) and /etc/passwd values had changed.

so my question is, is it possible to change the way of authenticating linux?

P.S : I found an extra entry inside /etc/rc.sysinit which will lead to run 23 extra services but none of them is involved in changing /etc/passwd values after typing 3 wrong passwords in a row (or at least I couldn't find any clue).

Answer (score 1):

You got 0wn3d... the only safe way out is to disconnect from the network, rescue any important data (preferrably using a LiveCD or a rescue CD), and install from scratch. The rescued data has to be considered *highly* suspect until carefully scrutinized for fishy goings on.

If FC4 means Fedora Core 4, that is **long** past end of life. Can't you update? If updating yearly is a problem, consider [CentOS](http://www.centos.org).

Comment: I really want to know how can I do such thing?and which files are responsible for authenticating?